# JQuery UI Slider widget Not able to display slider value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using the Slider widget, as a range from 0 to 500000, in my rails web app. I'm trying to display the value of slider as it changes, but I don't know where I'm wrong. I'm new to JQuery, help would be much appreciated.

**JQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var slider = $("#the_slider").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500000,
        step: 1,
        values: [0, 500000],
        animate: 'slow',
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#q_rent_gteq").val(ui.values[0]);
            $("#q_rent_lteq").val(ui.values[1]);
        },
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.handle).find('span').html('&#3647' + ui.value[0]);
            $(ui.handle).find('span').html('&#3647' + ui.value[1]);
        }
    });
    $("#q_rent_gteq").val(slider.slider("values")[0]);
    $("#q_rent_lteq").val(slider.slider("values")[1]);
});
</script>
```

**View:**

```
<div id="the_slider"></div>
<span id="q_rent_gteq"></span>
<span id="q_rent_lteq"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text` if `#q_rent_gteq` or `#q_rent_lteq` are not inputs, textareas or selects. Other than this I cannot reproduce your error. Also combine both your slides. There is no need for two

```
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#q_rent_gteq").val(ui.values[0]);
        $("#q_rent_lteq").val(ui.values[1]);
        $(ui.handle).html('&#3647' + ui.values[0]);
        $(ui.handle).html('&#3647' + ui.values[1]);
    }
```

Also `ui.handle` is a span itself. Did you mean to find that `span` or another? I don't see any others in the jQuery slider that can be found with a `.find`.

https://jsfiddle.net/eu793by7/